# Python - download a file from URL

Tags: python

I would like to know, how to download a file from a specific URL without knowing file type and name in Python? Simply like downloading it by opening via browser.

**URL example**:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/PortableApps.com%20Platform/PortableApps.com_Platform_Setup_19.0.paf.exe/download?use_mirror=deac-fra&use_mirror=deac-fra&r=

Comment: If you have a URL for the file, you can use `requests` or a similar library to download it.

Comment: What have you researched so far? There are plenty of existing posts here about this exact thing. I've seen in some of them that they had success using the `content-disposition` header; did that not work for you? Did you try using the `requests` library? So far you haven't indicated what you've tried, which you really should, so people don't waste their time looking into things you've already attempted.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```py
import requests
URL = "http://www.example.com"
with open ("Filename", "wb") as f:
    f.write(requests.get(URL).content)
```